# Arguments Value Not Defined error in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

For the code given below , when Edit is Clicked the argument pass to parameter the function become like this

```
EditItem(LDU_1) //LDU_1 is that itemid
```

however i am getting an error during this operation:

```
LDU_1 is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

Code listing is shared below

```
`<a href='#' class='btn btn-info' onclick='EditItem(" + ItemId + ")'>Edit</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>

function EditItem(itemId) {
        var url = "Home/GetItemById?itemId=" + itemId;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                //...
            })
        })
```

`

Comment: On very first line, onclick='EditItem(" + ItemId + ")' , is ItemId defined?

Comment: try onclick='EditItem(" + 1+ ")' just to check if it works with it, then you have to define that ItemId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `ItemId` as string by double code escape like following.

```
"<a href='#' class='btn btn-info' onclick='EditItem(\"" + ItemId + "\")'>Edit</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
```

Comment: it immediately worked, thank u verry much